# Laravel - Import new Vue Component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I started working with Vue JS and I want to use it in my laravel project. The Laravel version I'm working with is 5.5

I have a vueTest.blade.php. Looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Vue Test
    </title>
    <style href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet"></style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <example-component></example-component>
    <test></test> <<<----- This component is the problem! 
</div>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This  comes with laravel and works fine. the test component however is written by me and doesn't work at all. No errors in the console.

At the bottom of the html file, I'm including the app.js ( Thats where vue.js starts in laravel )

The app.js looks like this:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('test', require('./components/Test.vue')); <<--- Thats the only line I addet

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

And the Test.vue is this:

```
<template>
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <p>Bla bla bla</p>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

    }
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

I tried many things out but nothing worked for me at all. Do I have to register my new components anywhere else? There are no errors in the console and I can't see where the problem is.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what about `example-component` is it working ?

Comment: like I said, yes it's working perfectl fine

Comment: Did you `npm run dev` or `yarn run dev` after you added this javascript?

Comment: huh, that solved the problem. Weird. Write a answer and I will mark it as the right answer :)

Comment: Another question, whenever I change my components, I have to run npm dev. Otherwise the changes are not accepted. That's not normal, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template needs to have a root element:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>hello</h1>
        <p>Bla bla bla</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

And better run `npm run watch` because it needs to compile on every update.